# Bit pattern probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have 8 bit´s 4 ones and 4 zeros and 8 bit string is built by randomly choosing all of these 8 bits.

What is the probability that there are no ones next to each other, meaning that 11001100 would be illegal string, because there are ones next to each other but 10101010 would be accepted.

I have no idea how to approach this problem, should i do something like: $\frac{a}{b},$ where a is number of all accepted permutation and b is number of all possible permutations ? Or can this be solved by using some probability distribution ?

Comment: Are strings allowed to begin with a zero?

Comment: Yes, they can begin with zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take the four zeros $*0*0*0*0*$ there are five possible places marked by $*$ which can take a $1$ - but none of these can take two ones. Placing four ones will leave one of the $*$s unfilled. You should be able to count the possibilities.

Now you need to compute the number of possible sequences of four ones and four zeros - hint: four out of the eight positions will be taken by ones.

You should be able to make it yourself from there.

Comment: Very nice, simple and effective.